how to turn off fps counter libvulkan
trying fix problem with vulkan shaders processing on steam i found this command:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-535 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386

It did not helped but now i have fps counter on top left side of my screen in applications, even in google chrome
it says:
GL <fps number> FPS
BLIT - VSYNC ON (or off in some applications)


How can I turn off this counter?

You've not provided the starting details useful to help... ie. what OS/release are you using?  PPAs are 3rd party sources (Personal Package Archives) that do not provide support for all releases, so checks are on you, and you've not provided the starting point (which is knowing what you're running) allowing us to provide any help with PPAs.  What are you actually running?  What architecture?

Sorry, I did not know that about PPA (used it for the first time)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
